# How do I make my Redditbot target-search a specific user, comment, and/or thread instead of an entire subreddit?

Tags: python, bots, reddit, praw

This is my first time coding, and as such I think my problem is most likely general confusion and difficulty with terms. I have the login function and the reply functions working on my bot, but I'm stuck at what command to use to narrow my bot's search-for-keyword range to a specific thread and or user, instead of an entire subreddit.

I've tried looking at the PRAW documentation and Build-A-Bot tutorials online, but I can't find any compatible commands in Python/PRAW to search a specific Redditor, comment, or subreddit thread.

This is the original command for PRAW that makes my bot search the subreddit for its key phrase:

`for comment in r.subreddit('').comments(limit=25):`

But I'm trying to hone it in on searching more specifically, so I tried this:

```
for comment in r.submission('#portion of the URL that has the submission ID in it').comments(limit=25):
```

But that just returns `"TypeError: 'CommentForest' object is not callable."`

I've also tried:

```
for comment in r.user('#Redditor name').comments(limit=25):
```

But that just returns `"TypeError: 'User' object is not callable."`

I have zero coding background and I'm actually having a lot of fun with Python thus far! I'm just stuck at this point. Any help and or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `redditor` rather than `user`. From the praw docs:

```
# assume you have a Submission instance bound to variable `submission`
redditor1 = submission.author
print(redditor1.name)  # Output: name of the redditor

# assume you have a Reddit instance bound to variable `reddit`
redditor2 = reddit.redditor('bboe')
print(redditor2.link_karma)  # Output: bboe's karma
```

You may have already seen them, but the docs can be found [here](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html#obtain-redditor-instances).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! I've seen the documentation you referenced, but maybe I'm just confused how to actually use it.

I've tried:

for comment in r.redditor('#Redditor name').comments(limit=25):

And it returns "Type Error: 'SubListing' object is not callable"

Seems like I'm a little out of my depth. I keep running into uncallable objects, and I'm not even sure what that means to be honest. In anycase, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Pie-a-thon replace `.comments(limit=25)` with `.comments.new(limit=25)`. You could also use another listing, such as `hot` or `top`.